# Files generated in JUnit Tests while executed in Idea but not when executed via mvn test

Tags: java, maven, junit, swagger, springfox

I hava a JUnit test which generates some asciidoc files from an springfox swagger endpoint. These files are generated if I execute the test from Idea, but are not generated if I execute the test via mvn test. Is there a way to fix this?

```
  @Test
  public void convertSwaggerToAsciiDoc() throws Exception {
      this.mockMvc.perform(get("/v2/api-docs")
              .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
              .andDo(Swagger2MarkupResultHandler.outputDirectory("src/docs/asciidoc/generated")
                         .build())
              .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

The generated files should be processed further with asciidoctor via maven-asciidoctor-plugin:

```
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <sourceDirectory>src/docs/asciidoc/generated</sourceDirectory>
      <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/public/doc/</outputDirectory>
      <sourceDocumentName>index.adoc</sourceDocumentName>
      <backend>html5</backend>
      <sourceHighlighter>coderay</sourceHighlighter>
      <attributes>
        <toc>left</toc>
      </attributes>
      <headerFooter>true</headerFooter>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>output-html</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But the files are not updated if I execute 'mvn package'.

Comment: From which directory are you running `mvn package`?  Is this a mutli-module maven project - i.e. are you executing `mvn package` on the project itself or on a parent module?

Comment: It is a single module maven project. There is only one pom.xml in this project. I execute `mvn package` from the projects root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ runs all test it finds in the src/test/java folder only looking at the annotations.

The maven test runner only check files where the filename ends in *Test*. So check the Name of your test class if it ends with `Test` (Alas you did not show the whole test class definition).

Comment: If I run `mvn test` I see that the tests are executed.

Comment: I have to correct me. The test wasn't executed and the reason was that the file name didn't ends with _Test_, as you said. Now everything works as expected and all files are created.